# get from textfile line line and split them

Tags: c++, c++11

i have a text file file is person.txt, i want to read line, line and keep from each specific variable. the text is as follows

```
 (person
   (name "Jony")
   (Surname "Black")
   (Other )
   (DATE "Thu Nov  3 17:29:33 2016")
   (INSTANCE  people
      (NET 
         (cal (A 4000232000) (B 4000233000) (G 0) (H 0) (I 0) (C 4000232))
         (ree (A 8000065000) (B 400000) (G 0) (H 0) (I 0) (C 2))
         (op1\[0\] (A 4000061000) (B 4000404000) (G 0) (H 0) (I 0) (C 1000248))
     and so on
```

I want to get the name surname, Date, instance, and A,B,G,H,I,C.

I try with `getline(input_file, name, '(')` but is not a good idea. the patern of () it is difficult for me. If can anyone help me to understand how to split every line and get the values i need.
Thanks

Comment: What's the name of that format?

Comment: A regex looks like it would work for this.

Comment: I would probably use `getline(input_file, name, '(')`. Why isn't that working for you?

Comment: because i want "jony" from first line from the second line i want the "Black" and so on

Comment: Why don't use stack?

Comment: It seems like there's a nested object structure (like a tree of strings) in this file format, sort of like JSON. You would be better off parsing this by tracking the tree depth from the `(` and `)` characters rather than approaching it from a "line by line" solution. From there, the first token inside a `(key value)` pair would be the name of the node in the hierarchy, and the 2nd token would be the value, either a string (leaf) or more branches (`(key (...)(...)(...))`). Take a look at how state machines can be used to parse JSON, you can build a similar system to parse this format.

Comment: Actually, is converting this text file to JSON first and then parsing the JSON an acceptable solution? The format is similar enough that a regex replace might get you valid JSON.

Comment: This may be a bit heavy handed for your problem, but have you considered using a parser generator such as [ANTLR](https://www.antlr.org/)? If you can't convert this to a specification that is more readily supported such as JSON, then defining a small domain specific language in ANTLR can save you a lot of time trying to make a good parser by hand.

Comment: Are A,B,G,H,I,C going to be arrays of values or you are only interested in the very first set of those value?

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code?

Comment: @boyanhristov96 Yes they going to be arrays one for A values, one for B values and so on.

Comment: @Romen is possible to give an example in code ?

Comment: @Vagos, I would need to see the whole text file to begin writing something to parse it. But it would be *much* easier to try my JSON approach first. Would you accept an answer that does a regex-replace on the text file to convert it to JSON? If you can convert it to JSON format you can use something like [JSON for Modern C++](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) to load and traverse the data in C++.